# Spring Batch: Is there a pattern for this?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using a `PoiItemReader`, and I need to partially read a file, perform some database logging with the partial contents, then map the rest of the file to my item. It seems as though the only way to do this is through the `RowMapper`, but there's a lot of data I'd need to inject into the mapper, and this all smells like a bad design.

Is there a Spring Batch pattern for chaining readers, or something like that?

The reason I want to do this is that I don't want validation errors to prevent me from logging into the database. That step HAS to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to chain readers. You need a custom `ItemReader` implementation if you want to do that.